# Create a listBox containing Buttons, and periodically one button is selected (kind of carousel)

Tags: c#, listbox, carousel

I want to create a listbox that contains buttons, and each time one button is selected (animation) my code is  like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="sa.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="108" d:DesignWidth="592" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:sa">

    <Grid Width="572">
        <ListBox  Name="ListBoxV"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  Height="96" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="572"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="30 0 30 0" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>


        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


 public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

           List<Temp> ListItems = new List<Temp>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                ListItems.Add(new  Temp("a"+i));
            }

            ListBoxV.ItemsSource = ListItems;

            DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();

            dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);

            dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            dt.Start();
        }

        void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((ListBoxV.SelectedIndex + 1) < ListBoxV.Items.Count)
                ListBoxV.SelectedIndex = ListBoxV.SelectedIndex + 1;
            else
                ListBoxV.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ListBoxV.ScrollIntoView(ListBoxV.SelectedItem);
        }

        public class Temp
        {
               public Temp(string s)
               {Button b = new Button();
                b.Name=s;            }


        }
    }
```

The listbox don't display buttons, only the animation is working 
affich "sa.UserControl2.Temp" for every element.

When displaying if the end of the list, it want back to the begin of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues here. I suggest you read up on [DataTemplates](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) and [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

First of all, the items you use to fill in the ListBox (or whatever other `ItemsControl`-based element) should be Data Items, stricly. These cannot contain such thing as `Button`s. It's much better to maintain Application Logic and UI separated in WPF.

Here is an example of your ListBox with an ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox  Name="ListBoxV"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
          Height="96" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="572"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="30 0 30 0" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Button Content="{Binding Property}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Data Item:

```
public class Temp
{
    string Property {get;set;}

    public Temp(string s)
    {
        Property = s;
    }
}
```

Also note that in order to support updates on the UI when you change these properties in the class `Temp`, it will have to implement the [`System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

Then, if you want to perform an action when the button is clicked for each item, you will have to use an [`ICommand`](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html):

```
public class Temp
{
    string Property {get;set;}

    public Temp(string s)
    {
        Property = s;
        DoSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand(x => DoSomething());
    }

    public DelegateCommand DoSomethingCommand {get;set;}

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        //DoSomething when the Button is Clicked!!
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Property}" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display buttons in your ListBox you have to write ItemTemplate for it. It would look like this one:

```
<ListBox  Name="ListBoxV"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  Height="96" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="572"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="30 0 30 0" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 <ListBox.ItemTempate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <Button Content="{Binding Property}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTempate>
```

Next, you don't need to add buttons to your collection of ListBox's items, strings will be just fine. So your class Temp needs to be changed to just this:

```
class Temp{
    string Property {get;set;}
    public Temp(string s){
        Property = s;
    }
}
```

With these changes you will have listbox with buttons inside it. Those buttons will have text from Temp.Property property displayed.

Comment: thanks, one more thing pleese for the animation, it ends without a retour to the first index, is there a solution for that